# NGXS update array of objects that contain array of objects using store operators

Tags: angular, ngxs

Considering the following type definitions for my objects:

```js
export interface Payment {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly taxes: ReadonlyArray<Datum>;
}

export interface Datum {
    readonly type: string;
    readonly value: number;
}
```

And my state looks as follows:

```js
const data: Payment[] = [
    {
        id: '1',
        taxes: [
            {
                type: 'One',
                value: 123
            },
            {
                type: 'Two',
                value: 123
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        taxes: [
            {
                type: 'One',
                value: 456
            },
            {
                type: 'Two',
                value: 456
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I want to issue a command that would update a specific payment tax. It looks as follows:

```js
export class UpdateTax {
    public static readonly type = '[Payments] Update Tax';
    constructor(public readonly id: string, public readonly type: string, public readonly value: number) {}
}
```

How can I update specific tax object using NGXS operators? I can do that just fine using spread operator and mapping it all manually, that's no problem, however I am curious how could I achieve that using state operators.

My attempt is:

```js
setState(
    patch({
        payments: updateItem(
            p => !!p && p.id === id,
            patch({
                taxes: updateItem(t => !!t && t.type === type, patch({ value }))
            })
        )
    })
);
```

Strangely this works but shows me the following error:

```
Argument of type '<U extends PatchValues<{ taxes: Datum[] | StateOperator<Datum[]>; }>>(existing: Readonly<U>) => U' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Payment | StateOperator<Payment>'.
  Type '<U extends PatchValues<{ taxes: Datum[] | StateOperator<Datum[]>; }>>(existing: Readonly<U>) => U' is not assignable to type 'StateOperator<Payment>'.
    Types of parameters 'existing' and 'existing' are incompatible.
      Type 'Readonly<Payment>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<PatchValues<{ taxes: Datum[] | StateOperator<Datum[]>; }>>'.
        Types of property 'taxes' are incompatible.
          Type 'readonly Datum[]' is not assignable to type 'Datum[] | StateOperator<Datum[]> | undefined'.
            The type 'readonly Datum[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Datum[]'.
```

I have enabled strict mode in tsconfig.

Comment: Have a look at https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction it allows all those cool operators while maintaining immutability. There is also an adapter for ngxs: https://github.com/ngxs-labs/immer-adapter

Comment: @DanielHabenicht I did check immer, however all the examples I was able to find were quite primitive - e.g. how to push an item to an existing array... I'd be more than happy to use immer as well instead of state operators.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas just remove `readonly` keyword from your interfaces. It's not needed. Your state is already runtime read-only because it's `Object.freeze`d in the development mode, thus you will get an error trying to mutate it :)

Comment: @overthesanity that was really it. Thanks you!